# Angular2 - *ngFor and *ngIf on same element producing error

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of users and I want to show only male users on the table. Here is how I am trying to achieve this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template:`
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="#user of users" *ngIf="user.gender == 'male' " >
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    `
})
export class AppCmp{
    public users = [
        {
            name: "Eesa",
            gender: "male"
        },
        {
            name: "Abdullah",
            gender: "male"
        },
        {
            name: "Javeria",
            gender: "female"
        }
    ]
}

bootstrap(AppCmp);
```

but I am getting the following error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined

as you can see I am using *ngFor and *ngIf on the same element i.e. `tr`. Why can't I use *ngFor and *ngIf on the same element? Is there any other way of achieving this? I re-produced the problem [here on plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Ro92iRwc7MlNAj2xf9jo/) you can see the error on the console.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In fact, ngIf and ngFor on a same element isn't supported. You could use the expanded syntax of `ngIf` to be able to implement this:

Initial version:

```html
<tr *ngFor="#user of users">
  <template [ngIf]="user.gender == 'male'">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
  </template>
</tr>
```

Updated version with latest Angular selectors.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">  
  <tr *ngIf="user.gender == 'male'">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: omg thanks so much I was having a hard time debugging and ngFor and ngIf on same elements this saved me :)

Comment: you are a genius +1