# Why ng-template is not working in Angular?

Tags: angular

We can't use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element. A technique is to nest them. Almost everywhere it's OK, except in tables when we want to both loop over `tr` and print them conditionally.

As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026219/angular2-ngfor-and-ngif-on-same-element-producing-error) we should use `<template>`, or [`<ng-template>`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) elements, so that it won't be printed to the DOM.

But I can't make it work. It simply doesn't print out anything. [Here's a plunker to show it in action](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tMpJFIOhV6LQt810?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview).

What should I do?

Answer (score 12):

As *ngIf is rendered as [ngIf], try using [ngIf] directly on template it should work.

> When we prepend a directive with * we are telling it to use the
>   element it’s attached to as the template. Basically *ngIf is a combo of
>   ng-template + [ng-If].

**Html:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
   <ng-template [ngIf]="item.month == 12">
        <td>{{ item.year }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.month }}</td>
   </ng-template>
</tr>
```

or simply you can decorate with *ngIf

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div ngIf*="item.month == 12">
        <td>{{ item.year }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.month }}</td>
   </div>
</tr>
```

updated **[plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/TNOPMGzWbereZXek?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)**

Useful **[article](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/structural-directives/)** on Structural directives

Answer (score 9):

so there is something call **ng-container** also,

> ng-container and ng-template Both of them are at the moment (2.x, 4.x)
>   used to group elements together without having to introduce another
>   element which will be rendered on the page (such as div or span).

the difference between ng-template and ng-container is

ng-template is used for a structural directive like ng-if, ng-for and ng-switch. If you use it without the structural directive, nothing happens and renders.

ng-container is used when you don't have a suitable wrapper or parent container. In most cases, we are using div or span as a container but in such cases when you want to use multiple structural directives, but you can't use more than one structural directive on an element, in that case, ng-container can be used as a container

in your case

`<ng-template>` is used to declare a template. What you want here is to hide/display some nodes

so you need to use ng-container for the same like

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.month == 12">
        <td>{{ item.year }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.month }}</td>
    </ng-container>
</tr>
```

there are couple of links which will help you to understand the both

related [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17111)

[structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

[discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11994) on ng-template and ng-container

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you might get ng-template work when it is used to replace the else case while using `*ngIF`

```
<p *ngIf="a > b; else notTrue"> A Is Greater Than B <p>
<ng-template #notTrue>
  <> B Is Greater Than A <p>
</ng-template>
```

Inside the first paragraph tag create a variable called `notTrue` and use it inside the **ng-template** tag to print the line in the paragraph if `a < b`,

Answer (score 1):

I hope you might have found the answer by now. This is for people who are not yet stumbled upon the answer. 
A better way to interpret the `ng-template` is a template element that angular uses with a structural directive (*ngIf, *ngSwitch)  that gets compiled to generate the structures inside it. The issue with using the above structural directives along with a ng-template is that, when *ngIf is true a template will be generated. But nowhere we specify that this template should be rendered. An alternate approach is using the *ngIf as [ngIf] property binding value where the property bound should be a boolean value as such.

Now angular interprets that as the template should be generated and rendered on the boolean value being true. A very basic example is provided below.

( I am unable to use the pluker link. So here is my stackblitz[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yreg5f)

Hope this helps. There is a great article on this [ng-template](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)